# How do I push to Git Repo given the following error: An internal Exception occurred during push: ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git: session is down

Tags: eclipse, ssh, egit

I recently set up a github account to store the source code of a project I have been working on.

I am using **egit eclipse** plugin to push changes to *github*.

I successfully pushed the initial code and 2 subsequent changes. However when I attempted to push the third change I was not able. The following excepiton appears in the eclipse error log.

If someone could tell me the cause of this error, or tell me how I can go about debugging the problem it would be a great help.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of push command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI.execute(PushOperationUI.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI$1.run(PushOperationUI.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git: session is down
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.<init>(JschSession.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.<init>(JschSession.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession.exec(JschSession.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshPushConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openPush(TransportGitSsh.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1120)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:152)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.openChannel(Session.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschSession$JschProcess.<init>(JschSession.java:147)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post a screen of your push configuration in egit? It's Team > Remote > Confrigure Push To Upstream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. Resolution follows:

- Delete origin push and fetch in remote(`Eclipse view --> Git repositories`).
- Close Eclipse.
- Go to `.ssh` folder(Users/.ssh) and delete the key files(**public** and **private**).
- Start eclipse and regenerate the keys(`Window --> Preferences --> General tab --> Network connections --> SSH2`).
- Copy the key and add it to `github/SSH` Keys
- In Eclipse add *new remote* and **push**.

---

**Edit**
You may not need to delete all the key files. If you have already added a key file previously (perhaps while setting up native Git), you can just add the name of that file in list of keys, and it will work.

Comment: what does this mean in 1st point above - "Delete origin push"  ?

Answer (score 4):

This seemed to work for me:

Do everything Firoz and Nishant say except **push**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889350

Create or edit the following file on your desktop:

File    : **~/.ssh/config**
Content :

```
Host github.com
    User [your_github_username]
    Hostname github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile [path_to_private_key]
```

In your Eclipse Git Setup for your project do the following:

1. URI      : **git**@github.com:[repo_owner_username]/[repo_name].git
2. Protocol : ssh
3. Username : **git**
4. Password : [leave_blank]
5. Save and push.

See this GitHub SSH Help page for useful info: http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Worked for me after initially suffering through "session is down" and "cannot open git-upload-pack" errors. Hope it helps everyone else too.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and I found out solution which is extremely foolish. 
I took following steps:

- I logged into *git repository* of my project from *browser* and didn't sign out.
- I copied the **http url** to *push* or *pull* from project repository from *github*.
- I pasted the *url* in my *eclipse plugin* while pushing code (didn't use the already stored one even though both of them were same)

I don't know what and why but above steps have worked for me whenever I have faced above problem. I don't know why does eclipse throw such exceptions and why does it gets solved this way.

You can also try pushing using other ways outside of eclipse. for eg. `TortoiseGit` or `SmartGit` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by pointing the **JAVA_HOME** variable to **jdk 6**. It was originally pointing to **jdk 5**.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message and it was fixed when one of my co-workers emailed me the two files id_rsa and id_rsa (MS Pub doc), I put them in C:Users\[userID]\.ssh, and shut down and restarted my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with EGit and solved it at last. Somehow sometimes things get messed up. If you can not solve it through Eclipse just go to your "git" folder with git bash with Windows. With Linux it is even easier: just open the terminal.

This problem occurs because of username, password, and ssh keys getting messed up. 
So, use the commands "git remote show origin" and make sure if the origin is `username@github.com......` Sometimes Eclipse just puts "git" as a username so make sure you have the correct user name by changing it with the command `git remote set-url origin https://usrname@github.com/restofthe url`. It should automatically change the configurations in eclipse.

Best...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

The following command in Git Bash, comes handy in such scenarios: git remote prune origin

This configured the Pull/Push in the corrupted branch.