# Unable to use egit to clone a repository with ssh

Tags: ssh, egit

I try to clone a GIT repository with EGit using SSH. I can log on to the machine, see the available branches and choose where to put everything locally. Then when I proceed to actually do the cloning, I get an Eclipse "Problem Occured" box stating:
"Cloning from ssh://[my user name]@[my address] has encountered a problem. ssh://[my user name]@[my address]: Password:". The details for the problem only list "ssh://[my user name]@[my address]: Password:" twice.

The only possible reason I can think of, might be that on the remote compute only Git 1.6.0.x is installed - and I don't have the rights to update it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I push to Git Repo given the following error: An internal Exception occurred during push: ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git: session is down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003840/how-do-i-push-to-git-repo-given-the-following-error-an-internal-exception-occur)

Answer (score 0):

Can you clone the repository using native git? If you can do that, just clone it using native git and then import the project into eclipse using:

```
File -> Import -> Projects from Git -> Local
```

If your eclipse runs on Windows, you will need a linux machine (virtual machine will do) and clone the repo into a NTFS or Fat32 formatted storage. Then you will be able to copy the cloned repo into your git folder on the windows machine.