# Egit (Eclipse) can see repository but won't clone it

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, clone, egit

I'm trying to clone a repository using ssh. From the command line it works fine, but when I use Egit in Eclipse it doesn't work. I get the following error message:

```
Git repository clone failed.
ssh://user@host: Password:
```

The error log only shows:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://lee@137.248.191.189:22: Password: 
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.get(UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProvider.get(CredentialsProvider.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProviderUserInfo.promptKeyboardInteractive(CredentialsProviderUserInfo.java:142)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.start(UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.java:135)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$5.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

According to [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/769084/) it seems to be because I'm using JDK7. Unfortunately, I don't have the option of not doing so. It seems I'm not the only person having this problem - another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506880/unable-to-use-egit-to-clone-a-repository-with-ssh) mentions it.

Git works fine on the command line, so I could just clone the repository and then import the project locally, but it's lame to have to always switch between CL and IDE.

Comment: What's the exception encountered?

Comment: Where would I be able to find out the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) … no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine/2843837#2843837)", you do have the option to use JDK6 to launch your Eclipse.
That doesn't prevent you to reference a JDK7 in the "Installed JRE" section, for your programs to compile/run.

If you still want to access the Git repo through a JDK7-run Eclipse, then you must add the missing certificate in the JDK7 keystore, as [described here (ofr https access)](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/SSH+certificate) or [here (for ssh access)](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210).

But for ssh issue, this could be related to [bug 360862](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=360862):

[image: error]

Comment: You're right, I seem to be a victim of that bug... I guess I'll give https a try then.