# Eclipse git push to repository - origin has encountered a problem

Tags: git, eclipse, github, repository, egit

this is the first project I actively use git for.
I am using eclipse and setup git on there a while ago.
Everything worked fine and I pushed more than 20 updates over the last few months, but now after this weekend I always get the following error whenever I want to push something.

`Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/MrElektronz/KniffelOWL (https://github.com/MrElektronz/KniffelOWL: git-receive-pack not permitted on 'https://github.com/MrElektronz/KniffelOWL/')`

And I don't think I have changed one thing in the settings (maybe I did now trying to fix it, but I don't know there the error comes from). As I said I am quite inexperienced with git and I would appreciate any help here :D.

*Oh and also: I found that maybe my username and password are wrong, because of this error message (doesn't make any sense to me, because I didn't change them and it worked before). But I also don't know where eclipse stores my password, so I can't even change it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git-receive-pack not permitted on Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475726/git-receive-pack-not-permitted-on-push)

Comment: Github no longer supports https access for git, you must use ssh.

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar unfortunately I came across this before, but it didn't really help me.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh is that so? Do you know where I can find the settings in eclipse to use the ssh string?

Comment: See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 that did the trick, thank you so much :D I wonder why this didn't show up when I googled it. Obviously I wasn't the only person experiencing this :/