# Pushing to github with netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, github, netbeans-7

I am new to using gitHub and I am using netBeans on macosx.

I am having trouble pushing the project. I get the following error:

```
https://Username@github.com/xxxfolder/xxxproject.git:git-receive-pack not permitted
```

I tried using a number of things like trying to log as ssh. But it didn't work.

I changed the rights to the local rep. to 777 just in case with option -R and still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh://` instead?

Comment: Yeah I did try with `ssh://` though I'm not sure I did it correctly. I just changed `https://` to `ssh://` then put my login and pass from gitHub and tried to push. That's how it is right?

Comment: Should be. If you get a `session down` error with ssh refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003840/how-do-i-push-to-git-repo-given-the-following-error-an-internal-exception-occur

Comment: @JaredMcAteer Thanks Jared for your help I solved it. Turns out the user wasn't added on the repository collaborators on GitHub. Sorry about that I'm quite new to using gitHub specially using it with code editors etc... Thanks again! Btw. the https adress is NOT the same adress from ssh. At least for my repo. Check on gitHub when you try ssh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

In case someone else has this problem it suffices to verify if the user is added as a collaborator on the repository settings of GitHub.

If that doesn't work try doing it on ssh and remember to check the address mentioned in gitHub as it is different than that of the Https protocol.